# Align two rectangle split horizontal nodes vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I'd like to be able to align vertically two or more `rectangle split horizontal` nodes such that the central vertical lines align. As far as I can make out, the coordinates for those lines aren't known until *after* the nodes have been created. This is as far as I have gotten, with the `north west` anchor of the bottom node aligning with the bottom of the center vertical line of the top node.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newsavebox{\leftbox}
\newsavebox{\rightbox}
\newcounter{blocknum}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.multipart}

%% Thanks to egreg, make lrbox global (requires etoolbox.sty):
\cslet{glrbox}\lrbox
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname glrbox\endcsname{\setbox}{\global\setbox}{}{}
\cslet{endglrbox}\endlrbox

\NewDocumentEnvironment{Recipe}{}{%
    \begin{glrbox}{\leftbox}
        \begin{varwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
}{%
        \end{varwidth}%
    \end{glrbox}%
    %%% More...
    \ifnum\theblocknum=0
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {\node[name=block-\theblocknum,
            draw,
            rectangle split,
            rectangle split parts=2,
            rectangle split horizontal]
            {\nodepart{one}\usebox{\leftbox}\nodepart{two}\usebox{\rightbox}};
            \coordinate (putit-\theblocknum) at (block-\theblocknum.text split |- block-\theblocknum.two split south);
        }
    \else
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {\node[name=block-\theblocknum,
            draw,
            anchor=north west,
            rectangle split,
            rectangle split parts=2,
            rectangle split horizontal] at  (putit-\previous)
            {\nodepart{one}\usebox{\leftbox}\nodepart{two}\usebox{\rightbox}};
            \coordinate (putit-\theblocknum) at (block-\theblocknum.text split |- block-\theblocknum.two split south);
        }
    \fi
    \xdef\previous{\theblocknum}
    \stepcounter{blocknum}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\righttext}{}{%
        \end{varwidth}%
    \end{glrbox}%
    \begin{glrbox}{\rightbox}
        \begin{varwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
}

%\setmainfont{}

\begin{document}

\begin{Recipe}
Left\strut
\righttext
Right\\1\\2\\3\\4\strut
\end{Recipe}

\begin{Recipe}
Left which is longer\strut
\righttext
Right which is certainly quite long\\1\\2\\3\\4\strut
\end{Recipe}

\end{document}
```

[image: vertically align horizontal split nodes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text split` or `one split` anchors works for me:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ draw, align=left,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split horizontal] (A) 
        {Left\strut \nodepart{two} Right\\1\\2\\3\\4\strut};

\node[ draw, align=left,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        below= -\pgflinewidth of A.one split south,
        anchor=one split north
        ] (B) 
        {Left which is longer\strut \nodepart{two} Right which is certainly quite long\\1\\2\\3\\4\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not an attempt to solve the problem in the way you try, but just to tell you that you can get the desired (?) output with `fit`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=left] (L1) {Left};
\node[align=left,right=0pt of L1] (R1) {Right\\1\\2\\3\\4\strut};
\node[fit=(L1)(R1),draw,inner sep=0pt](fit1){};
\draw (fit1.north -| R1.west) -- (fit1.south -| R1.west) coordinate (aux1);
%
\node[align=left,below=0pt of aux1,anchor=north west] (R2) {Right which is certainly quite long\\1\\2\\3\\4\strut};
\node[align=left,left=0pt of R2] (L2) {Left which is longer};
\node[fit=(L2)(R2),draw,inner sep=0pt](fit2){};
\draw (fit2.north -| R2.west) -- (fit2.south -| R2.west) coordinate (aux2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You seem to be very good at defining new environments, so I did not even try to do this here.

Comment: Wow. I never cease to be amazed with what `fit` can do -- nice job! I'll play with this...

Comment: @sgmoye I guess a purist might say you do not even need Ti*k*Z for that, rather that this can be done using a simple tabular. But I would not now how to do that properly, so let's wait for a proficient purist.;-)

Comment: Yes, a tabular might be possible, though, given the data, such a tabular might end up being large, unwieldy and difficult to maintain -- fragile. Keeping the pairs of data distinct in separate environments is, to my mind, cleaner and the preferred way to go. Still, I'll experiment...